# Master detail with navigation?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to use the Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail page to implement a Hamburger menu navigation.  The issue I'm having is that, depending on how I change the detail page, either the hamburger menu disappears but Back functionality works, or the hamburger stays but we lost the ability to navigate through the detail pages (the hardware/on screen back button returns the user to the device's home screen).

The issue is easy to replicate using the most current XF (2.3.4.247); create a new `Cross Platform App (Xamarin)` in Visual Studio.  Ensure all Nuget packages are up to date.  Then to the Shared Project, add a `MasterDetail` page called `MyMasterPage`.

By default in `MyMasterDetailPage.xaml.cs` in the `ListView_ItemSelected` there's a line `Detail = new NavigationPage(page)` which preserves the hamburger menu, but effectively doesn't navigate between detail pages.  Pressing back on Android closed the app.

If you change the line to `Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page, true)` the back button works and you can navigate through all the previously opened sub items, but the hamburger icon is replace with another `back` button (in addition to the one the device normally shows).

How can I get the hamburger menu to stay so the user can access it on all pages, while still allowing the user to go back to previous Detail pages?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this example. https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage

On my App.xaml.cs I have it redirecting to the Menu page.

```
MainPage = new MainMenu();
```

Next I created the MainMenu view which is a MasterDetailPage

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <ContentPage 
            Icon="hamburger_menu.png" 
            Title="MyTitle"
            BackgroundColor="#29632A"
            >

        <!--Menu Title background color--> 

         <!--Slide out Menu--> 
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

            <!--Menu Header Layout-->

            <Label 
                Text="MyTitle" 
                TextColor="White" 
                FontSize="22" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                Margin="0, -10, 0, 5" />

            <ListView 
                    x:Name="MenuListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}"
                    ItemSelected="MainMenuItem_Selected"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    SeparatorVisibility="None" 
                    BackgroundColor="#f5f5f5">
                 <!--Menu background color--> 
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0,0,0">
                                     <!--Menu layout-->

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="18" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

The MainMenu.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainMenu : MasterDetailPage
{
    public List<MainMenuItem> MainMenuItems { get; set; }

    public MainMenu ()
    {
        BindingContext = this;

        // Build the Menu
        MainMenuItems = new List<MainMenuItem>()
        {
            new MainMenuItem() { Title = "Menu1", Icon = "menu1.png", IconSize = 18, TargetType = typeof(Menu1) },
            new MainMenuItem() { Title = "Menu2", Icon = "menu2.png", IconSize = 18, TargetType = typeof(Menu2) }
        };

        // Set the default page, this is the "home" page.
        ChangeDetail(new Menu1());
        InitializeComponent ();

    }

    // When a MenuItem is selected.
    public void MainMenuItem_Selected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MainMenuItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Title.Equals("Menu1"))
            {
                ChangeDetail(new Menu1());
            }
            else if (item.Title.Equals("Menu2"))
            {
                ChangeDetail(new Menu2());
            }

            MenuListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeDetail(Page page)
    {
        var navigationPage = Detail as NavigationPage;
        if (navigationPage != null)
        {
            navigationPage.PushAsync(page);
            return;
        }
        Detail = new NavigationPage(page) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000"), BarTextColor = Color.White };
    }
}
```

Comment: From my question:  "By default in MyMasterDetailPage.xaml.cs in the ListView_ItemSelected there's a line Detail = new NavigationPage(page) which preserves the hamburger menu, but effectively doesn't navigate between detail pages. **Pressing back on Android closed the app.**"

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what's happening?